# PLA prints with folded walls

Tags: print-quality, bambu-lab-p1p

Printer: Bambu Lab P1P
Filament: PLA (Ender Series)

All looks good, but for some reason, the outer walls are folded inwards a little bit. All walls are supposed to be straight. I printed it using Bambu Studio with default settings for Generic PLA.
What could cause such a defect and how to fix it?

Previously, I printed out a box that is a bit bigger with separative walls for minidiscs and it printed perfectly. In that model, other walls were thicker.

[image: Photo of a 3D printed model of a box with the outer walls bent inwards]

Comment: Does this happen across all speed modes ? have you tried calibrating to your filament

Comment: @F.Ahmed I have calibrated the filament, but haven't tried to experiment with speed modes. Thank you. Will try that.